# Why is my override to one template file not working?

Tags: template-override

I'm using Joomlashack's Novitas template, at a website updated with the LATEST extension and Joomla core updates as of two weeks ago.  I have a change I want to make to this file:

/templates/js_novitas/wright/adapters/joomla/nav.php

I put the change in THIS file, according to the directions provided by Joomlashack here:

/templates/js_novitas/html/layouts/joomla/toolbar/nav.php

https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla/easy-overrides/

But the change takes effect in the website only if the change is made to the original file within the template.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

I'm pretty sure the problem is not browser cache or server cache, as I've cleared both and simply by putting nav.php BACK into my /templates/js_novitas/wright/adapters/joomla/ folder, I can see the desired behavior.

Joomlashack Support won't answer, has requested that I ask my question again in this forum.

BTW, the purpose of my nav.php edit is to change the behavior for handhelds (iphones etc.) in the very top "toolbar" module.  Instead of making the website title disappear for narrow browser widths, I just let it get smaller and I've removed the "hamburger" button that toggles the website title in the toolbar module.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for fixing my easy-overrides link mickmackusa!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a layout and cannot be overridden normally.

Looking at the code, the template supports "overrides" of this file for specific Joomla minor versions. For instance, if you're using Joomla 3.10.x, you can create a file `templates/js_novitas/wright/adapters/joomla/joomla_310/nav.php` with `WrightAdapterJoomla310Nav` class in it. The downsides to this are that this file could be overwritten if template developers decide to include this file in an update and that you'd need to rename the file/class when updating a minor Joomla version (4.0, 4.1 and so on).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer Sharky!  Also the downsides you explained are much appreciated, for maintaining this override should I decide to use it.